# Обновление свойства, привязанного к контролу, из другого потока

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await

Всем привет. Есть **пользовательский элемент управления**. Упрощенная его разметка показана ниже:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.UI.Controls.MyControls">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Name="myCanvas"
                Background="{Binding MyBackground, 
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                             AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Codebehind** данного элемента управления:

```
public partial class MyCanvas : UserControl
{
    public MapControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static MapControl()
    {
        MyBackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.
            Register("MyBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(MapControl));
    }

    public static DependencyProperty MyBackgroundProperty;
    public Brush MyBackground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(MyBackgroundProperty);}

        set { SetValue(MyBackgroundProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Далее данный пользовательский элемент управления используется в главном окне приложения следующим образом:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.UI.MainWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.UI.MyControls"
        DataContext="{Binding MainWindowViewModel}>

   <Grid>

       <local:MyCanvas 
              MyBackground="{Binding Image, Mode=TwoWay}" />

   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Также есть следующая **MainWindowViewModel**, которая биндится к главному окну приложения:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IMyService _service;

    private ImageBrush _image; 
    public ImageBrush Image 
    {
        get { return _image; }

        set 
        { 
           _image= value; 
           OnPropertyChanged("Image"); 
        }
    }

     private int _zoom; 
     public int Zoom 
     {
          get { return _zoom; }

          set 
          { 
               _zoom = value; 
               OnPropertyChanged("Zoom");

               // Обновляю картинку асинхронно.
               UpdateImage();                
          }
     }

    private async void UpdateImage()
    {
        // Данный метод возвращает новую картинку!
        // Картинка возвращается как Task<ImageBrush>
        Image = await _service.GetNewImageTaskAync();

        // Далее происходит исключение:
        // Необходимо создать DependencySource в 
        // том же потоке, в котором создан DependencyObject
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что если я обновляю свойство **Image** данными, полученными из другого потока, то я получаю исключение "*Необходимо создать DependencySource в том же потоке, в котором создан DependencyObject*".

Пробовал по-разному синхронизировать потоки, но ничего не получилось.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне в свойство **Image** "положить" данные, созданные в другом потоке.

Comment: Если вы используете async/await, проблем быть не должно. Дайте больше кода. Например: как (в каком потоке) вы стартуете `UpdateData`? И что есть `MyData`?

Comment: @VladD, свойство Data биндиться к пользовательскому элементу управления. Может быть, причина ошибки в этом?

Comment: @sp7: Нет, не может быть. Пользовательские элементы управления ничем не отличаются от встроенных по сути.

А почему вообще у вас есть какие-то потоки при использовании async/await? Покажите всё же код, запускающий `UpdateData`. Я подозреваю, что вы запускаете потоки вручную (преступление!).

Comment: @VladD, отредактировал вопрос!

Comment: @VladD, спасибо! Помогли! После получения картинки вызвал Freeze() в методе GetNewImage(), который в свою очередь вызывается в GetNewImageTaskAync(), и все заработало! )) А то уже запарился с этой картинкой, все вроде синхронизировано - а не работает, что за фигня, думаю! ))

Comment: @sp7: Отлично, тогда преобразую в ответ.

Answer (score 5):

Кажется, понятно. Весь код, который вы привели, правильный. Ошибка должна быть в `GetNewImageTaskAync`. Либо нужно создавать image в UI-потоке, либо после создания вызвать на нём `Freeze()`.